# What brand of wireless router would be compatible with many broadband modems and easy to use?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, router, wireless-networking

Good afternoon

I'm having too many intermittent problems with my DLINK DIR 400 router: 
**Wireless connection is lost with no reason.**

Perhaps the current router is incompatible with this Scientific Atlanta cable modem DPC 2100R2.

**Scientific Atlanta** is a Cisco company, but I'm really worried about this combination DLink - Cisco.

Could anyone recommend me a good wireless router for Windows Vista / Windows 7?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try LinkSys home equipment with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) on it. LinkSys is a Cisco brand now... if that's any encouragement. However their firmware stinks as bad as it ever did, IMO. DD-WRT makes it amazing. The hardware is ubiquitous and should work with just about everything.

It should be noted that putting alternate firmware on the router may cause irreparable damage if not done properly. Read all the instructions on how to do it. That said, it's pretty simple. You may also void your warranty on it, but you're not losing much.

As for your issues with the cable modem, I doubt it's related to the kind of router your using. I could be wrong though. My suspicion would be that the DLink itself is flaky regardless of what modem is upstream of it.

Answer (score 1):

I agreee it is unlikey the Modem.  One major cause I have seen is power dips (brownouts)  Are the modem and wireless AP on a good UPS that provides brownout protection?